# Print generated pdf with GWT

Tags: gwt, printing, jasper-reports

I can open a generated jasper pdf report, in new tab with Window.open():

```
Window.open("report.pdf?traceCode=" + traceCode, "_BLANK", "");
```

If i want print the pdf file by clicking a button, what should i do? (Window.print() will print the entire page)

Comment: Not recommended but it would be possible only with other utility tools - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205180/how-to-print-a-pdf-from-the-browser

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own class and on click of Print button in your application, by using native print method you can call Window.Print().

GWT UIObject can be used for this purpose and the method and it will be converted into string.

```
public class NTPrint {
    /**
     * If true, use a Timer instead to print the internal frame
     */
    public static boolean USE_TIMER = true;

    /**
     * Time in seconds to wait before printing the internal frame when using Timer
     */
    public static int TIMER_DELAY = 1;

    public static native void it() /*-{ 
        $wnd.print(); 
    }-*/; 

    public static void it(String html) {
        try{
            buildFrame(html);
            if (USE_TIMER) {
                Timer timer = new Timer() {
                    public void run() {
                        printFrame();
                    }
                };
                timer.schedule(TIMER_DELAY * 1000);
            } else {
                printFrame();
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable exc) {
            CommonUtil.printStackTrace(exc);
            Window.alert(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will be called when you pass Widget without style.
     * @param uiObjects
     */
    public static void it( UIObject...uiObjects) { 
        StringBuffer objString= new StringBuffer();
        for(UIObject obj: uiObjects)
                objString.append(obj.toString());
            it("", objString.toString()); 
    }
```

}

**OnClick of Print button,**

```
  /**
         * prints all forms
         * @param documentInfo
         */
        public static void printForms(List<FormTransaction> formTransactions, String documentInfo, List<CellTransaction> cellTransactionList, boolean isComment, Document document) {
                String style = "<link rel='styleSheet' type='text/css' href='v4workflow/css/style.css'>"
                                + "<link rel='styleSheet' type='text/css' href='v4workflow/css/gwtcontrols.css'>"
                                + "<style type='text/css' media='print'>"
                                + "@media print {"
                                + ".footerText{font-size:13px; font-weight:normal;margin-top:0px;}"
                                + ".break {page-break-after:always}"
                                + "}" + "</style>";
                List<UIObject> uiObjects = new ArrayList<UIObject>();
                NTPrintLayout printLayout = new NTPrintLayout();
                printLayout.setSelectedDocument(null);
                uiObjects.add(createHeader());
                NTPrint.it(style,uiObjects);
        }

 public static FlexTable createHeader(){
                FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
                flexTable.setWidth("100%");
                return flexTable;
        }
```

Comment: I am not able to make out where the pdf file gets to be printed. Does the answer above print the Form instead?

Comment: @Ranna: +1 for the answer :)

Comment: @SSR, yes you got it right. You can pass all the UIObjects to the wnd.print function. As there is no way to print directly PDF directly.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to call the print() method (or any other method for that matter) of the window object if that window contains non-HTML page.

Let the user [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110090/send-a-file-from-server-to-client-in-gwt) the file.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382782/print-pass-a-file-reference-to-javascript-window-print-print-a-pdf-using-jav) also